# html5 invalid else statement

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have this html5 code in **mvc4**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @{
                    if(Model.ApartmentOption.hasWardrobes == true)
                        <img src="~/Images/true.png" />
                    else
                    <img src="~/Images/false.png" />
                    }
            </td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

but i got this exception

```
invalid else statement
```

what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: Think you need brackets `{` & `}`

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct syntax:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @{
                    if(Model.ApartmentOption.hasWardrobes == true) {
                        <img src="~/Images/true.png" />
                    } else {
                        <img src="~/Images/false.png" />
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

or:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @if(Model.ApartmentOption.hasWardrobes == true) {
                    <img src="~/Images/true.png" />
                } else {
                    <img src="~/Images/false.png" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just misplaced some brackets. To find more information about razor sintax: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

**Code working**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        @if(Model.ApartmentOption.hasWardrobes == true)
        {
            <img src='~/Images/true.png' />;
        }
        else
        {
         <img src='~/Images/false.png' />;
        }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```